# Acer D250 netbook battery won't charge

Tags: laptop, battery, netbook

The icon says the battery is 0%, plugged in, charging. Is in fact not charging. Tried a new battery, a new charger cord, updating BIOS, and downpowering and replugging the battery in repeated times.

The computer works fine plugged in with power cord, but shuts off immediately as soon as it is unplugged.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have BIOS revision 3309 (sometimes called 1.29) or later. Then follow this process:

1. Shut the laptop down.
2. Disconnect the power cord and remove the battery.
3. Push and hold the power button down for a full 2 minutes. Nothing will happen.
4. Re-install the battery.
5. Connect the power cord. Do not turn the laptop on.
6. Allow the laptop to sit for 2 hours.

Your battery should now have a charge.

Comment: didn't work, any other suggestions?